# Unable to access json data retrieved from php page using jquery $.ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

How to access this json data in JavaScript. 
when I alert it the result is `undefined`

Here is jQuery code

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "frmMktHelpGridd.php",
    data: {
        labNo: secondElement
    },
    dataType: "json",
    beforeSend: function () {
        // Do something before sending request to server
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert('error has occured');
        alert(errorThrown);
    },
    success: function (data) {

        //Here is the problem

        alert(data[0]['Result']);
    }
});
```

This is PHP code

```
            $data=array($no);
    for($i=0;($i<$no && ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)));$i++)
    {
        $data[$i]=array();
        $data[$i]['Result']         =   $row['Result'];         
        $data[$i]['TestCode']       =   $row['TestCode'];           
        $data[$i]['TestStatus']     =   $row['TestStatus'];         
        $data[$i]['SrNo']           =   $row['SrNo'];               
    }

    $data1=json_encode($data);

    echo $data1;
      exit;
```

I have tested the PHP file independently, 
The json data is output as follows:

```
      [{"Result":"1","TestCode":"22","TestStatus":"0","SrNo":"1"},{"Result":"1","TestCode":"23","TestStatus":"1","SrNo":"2"}]
```

Comment: side note: use `console.log` instead of `alert` thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "frmMktHelpGridd.php",
    data: {
        labNo: secondElement
    },
    dataType: "json",
    beforeSend: function () {
        // Do something before sending request to server
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert('error has occured');
        alert(errorThrown);
    },
    success: function (data) {
        //Added parse json
        var data = jQuery.parseJSON(data)

        alert(data[0]['Result']);
    }
});
```

Comment: same solution has been given before but it gives an error on console

Comment: I tried a bunch of different answers on this site .. none worked; and this finally did the trick - thanks!  In my case, I used the jQuery shortcut notation: var data = $.parseJSON(data);

Answer (score 0):

You can access to your data by doing

```
data[0].Result
```

It's an Object, not an array.

so `data[0]['Result']` it's not the proper way

**EDIT**:
Since you have more objects, you have to do a loop this way:

```
$.each(data, function(key, val){
    console.log(val.Result);
    console.log(val.TestCode);  
    //...
});
```

---

When you see something like

```
{
    "foo":"bar",
    ...
}
```

you can access to it the same way as above:

```
name_of_the_object.foo
```

that will have the value "bar"

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kevincittadini/WGXh4/ - It have to work (check your browser console to see results)

Comment: @sunny I apology I didn't give much attention to your JSON echo. I've seen only one object inside, but you got more so you have to do a loop, i'll update my answer too - This works :) http://jsfiddle.net/kevincittadini/WGXh4/2/

Comment: Correct and thanx for your precious time. Solved My Problem. I can't vote your answer UP because my reputation is under 15 yet(sorry)

Answer (score -1):

Try to add parse JSON. I have added. Now it may be work.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "frmMktHelpGridd.php",
    data: {
        labNo: secondElement
    },
    dataType: "json",
    beforeSend: function () {
        // Do something before sending request to server
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert('error has occured');
        alert(errorThrown);
    },
    success: function (data) {
        //Added parse json
        var data = $.parseJSON(data)

        alert(data[0]['Result']);
    }
});
```

Comment: tested your json object and it shows alert. Please check this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BcvC3/